# Making a Docker build stage depend on another stage without using anything from it

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to make a stage in a Docker multi-stage build depend on one or more stages *without using anything from them*? I.e., can I have stage X fail if stage Y fails, even though X doesn't use anything from Y?

**Details:**

My scenario is as follows: I have a single-page app (React + Javascript, but this doesn't matter) which uses a multi-stage Docker build which sets up a workspace, tests and compiles the code, and finally produces an image which uses Nginx to serve the SPA. Simplified, my Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM node:16.14.2-bullseye AS build
# Copy entire git repo (except .dockerignore'd files) into workspace
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Download dependencies
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Run tests
RUN yarn test

# Build app
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.23.1-alpine AS nginx
# Copy build output to nginx webroot
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

`yarn test` and `yarn build` exit with non-zero exit codes if they fail, and will so abort the build, just as it should be.

Furthermore, testing and building are also completely independent of each other, so I'd like to split the build up even more so I can run these steps in parallel, and then if they succeed, build the Nginx image. The following is *almost* what I want:

```
# Stage `workspace` - all files from the repo with dependencies installed
FROM node:16.14.2-bullseye AS workspace
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Stage `test` - run unit tests
FROM workspace AS test
RUN yarn test

# Stage `compile` - build the SPA
FROM workspace AS compile
RUN yarn build

# Stage `nginx`- serves the built site
FROM nginx:1.23.1-alpine AS nginx
COPY --from=compile /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I can now run `docker build --target=test .` to just run the tests, `docker build --target=compile .` to just build the SPA, and `docker build --target=nginx .` to get my Nginx image. If the `compile` stage fails, the Nginx packaging will fail, too, which is good. If the tests fail... well, there's nothing stopping us from building an Nginx image of my app from a code base which doesn't pass the tests, and I'd like to change that.

Here are a few options I thought up but didn't quite like:

- **Just make sure I run the tests in my build pipeline before I run the Nginx build.** Well, I already do this, but if someone messes up and happens to remove the test step, I'd still like the tests to be run. It's also nice to be able to see in the Dockerfile how things are expected to work.
- **Create an empty dummy file in the `test` stage (`touch TESTS_OK` or somesuch) and copy it into to the `nginx` stage (`COPY --from=test /app/TESTS_OK /`).** This makes the dependency explicit, but it feels a bit hackish copying a random file into a random place of my Nginx image.
- **Use an intermediate stage which copies files from both `compile` and `test` stages, and have the `nginx` stage copy the files it needs from this intermediate stage.** A bit like the previous option, except there's a level of indirection (annoying) which allows me to avoid sullying the Nginx image with random garbage files (good!).

So far, the last option is probably the one I dislike the least, but they're all hacks. Is there a better way of declaring that a stage requires another stage to be successful without actually using anything from it?

Comment: Could you switch `compile` so that it's based on test with `FROM test AS compile` ? This should ensure that when test fails, the whole build fails. However, then you'd lose the option of running testing and building in parallel.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I could, but the reason to split is to be able to parallelize the compile and test stages, so it wouldn't be much benefit, I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

> Can I have stage X fail if stage Y fails, even though X doesn't use anything from Y?

Using the modern BuildKit engine, if stage X is the final image and it doesn't use anything from Y, Docker won't even run the earlier stage.

I'd suggest running your unit-test sequence outside of Docker, before you build an image.  You should be able to configure your CI system to do the equivalent of:

```bash
yarn install
yarn test
docker build .
```

This also would let you omit the test code and dependencies from the final image, resulting in a smaller image and marginally faster build.

If it's really important to you to use no tool other than Docker, a trick from classic Makefiles is to have your test stage create an empty file on success, and then have the later stage copy that file.  Now there is "a dependency" even though it's not actually a meaningful file.

```bash
FROM workspace AS test
RUN yarn test \
 && touch /.tests-successful

FROM nginx:1.23.1-alpine
COPY --from=test /.tests-successful /
COPY --from=compile /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but perhaps you should read up on multi-stage builds - the final image (nginx) will not include node_modules, test code or any of that jazz. And I've already considered, and not grown very fond of, the Makefile-ish dummy file hack (as you can see, `touch TESTS_OK` and `COPY --from=test /app/TESTS_OK /`)